# Android: Need help fixing loop adding elements in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, loops, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Currently I have a two dimensional ArrayList of EditTexts.  Currently if a user enters in a 2x3 matrix (based on what is entered into the EditTexts) such as

```
[1 2 3]  
[4 5 6]
```

my code would create a Two-Dimensional ArrayList like below instead of like above

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]  
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

How do I get my code to produce an array like the first one instead of what it currently is producing?

My code:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener {    
   private static final String TAG = "Matrix";
    static ArrayList<EditText> columnEditTexts;
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<EditText>> arrayOfEditTexts = new ArrayList<ArrayList<EditText>>();

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       this.setContentView(R.layout.matrix);
       View doneButton = findViewById(R.id.done_button);
       doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
       columnEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();

       for(int i = 0; i < MatrixMultiply.h1; i++){
           TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
           TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
           EditText column = new EditText(this);
           for(int j = 0; j < MatrixMultiply.w1; j++){
               table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
               column = new EditText(this);
               column.setId(i);
               row.addView(column);
               columnEditTexts.add(column);
           }
           table.addView(row);
           arrayOfEditTexts.add(columnEditTexts);
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loop is adding elements to the same arraylist (columnEditTexts) on each iteration,  while your outer loop is adding the same columnEditTexts to arrayOfEditTexts. You need to set columnEditTexts to a new instance of ArrayList at the beginning of the outer loop.

Change this:

```
   columnEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();

   for(int i = 0; i < MatrixMultiply.h1; i++){
       TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
       TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
       EditText column = new EditText(this);
       for(int j = 0; j < MatrixMultiply.w1; j++){
```

to this:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < MatrixMultiply.h1; i++){
       columnEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();
       TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
       TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
       EditText column = new EditText(this);
       for(int j = 0; j < MatrixMultiply.w1; j++){
```